# Import unencrypted private key into ethereum wallet

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key, import

I have an ETH adress.
I have an unencrypted private key.

How to import these in MyEtherWallet? Or another Desktop Ether wallet?

Don't answer with an howto for Mist or Geth, because I use MyEtherWallet, and I do not see any import function.

Answer (score 2):

On MyEtherWallet, go to the tab Send Ether & Tokens. One of the options for loading a wallet is "Private Key". Click this and paste your unencrypted private key. The key should be 64 characters. Click Unlock to the right and you now have access to your wallet!

Comment: that is not any more the case I think. There isn't any "private key" reference in the MyEtherWallet once connected. It seems you are stuck with the address MEW generated for you during setup. Any update?